# How to run 4 processes exactly at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I need to run 4 Processes exactly at the same time, how to do it?

```
Process.Start();
Process.Start();
Process.Start();
Process.Start();
```

When i do it like this there are a milliseconds differences between all processes. I can't have any differences.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: You can't run anything on a computer *exactly at the same time*.  It's just a physical impossibility.

Comment: That's downright impossible.

Comment: This isn't possible, for reasons that should be self-evident.

Comment: Just round to the nearest second. :)

Comment: @roryap you do realize processors are multi core and actually process multiple things "at the exact same time" right? Also, GPUs have 1000s of processors and have been processing things at the "exact same time" since their conception.

Comment: @N_tro_P -- Yes, I know things are running at the same time in the processor.  You can't synchronize processes to run at *exactly* the same time.  Doing so requires that you can run the bit of code which executes the processes at exactly the same time.  This is a cyclical argument.

Comment: @roryap actually you can sync them. The HW has to provide the API to do so, which is more in line with what array processing is, i.e. GPUs. I am not aware of any Intel or AMD APIs that would allow it, but I am quite certain CUDA can handle it. You have to realize, the HW is not just a processer. There are registers that allow immediate context switching and in all modern CPUs there is more than one ALU.

Comment: @N_tro_P you are talking about SIMD (Single Intruction Multiple Data), I would not call that "4 processes", that is a single process working on 4 sets of data.

Comment: @N_tro_P Okay, I guess what I said was too broad and by "computer" I meant "Windows machine, on .NET, using only the FCL, standard hardware, etc."

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that is the most common usage of CUDA, but that is not its limitation. It can (AFAIK) handle different processes. I may be mistaken, however that was a suggestion. The fact is the HW can provide the API to do this and that is how it would be achieved. It is not "impossible".

Comment: @N_tro_P I will concede that I have never written CUDA code so I do not know what is fully possible with the API so you could be right.

Comment: @Jarek I'm glad you un-deleted this question.

Comment: @N_tro_P CUDA doesn't run "processes" in this sense, the Windows Kernel does. And the Windows Kernel has certain atomic operations that will prevent it from doing certain things at "exactly the same time". This has to do with preventing race conditions in multithreading. It is the responsibility of the program itself to synchronize execution if needed, the kernel does not give any guarantee whatsoever there. Unfair scheduling if you are talking about milliseconds happens all the time. IO-bound wait and disk was busy? Read different data in different sector? Easily out of sync with 10 ms+.

Comment: @TeddHansen I had thought there was a way to point to multiple process heads. If not then perhaps OpenGL. If not, that is quite silly considering the HW would allow it. It is easy to do on a FPGA because the clock is already there, just like in a GPU. You may be thinking of the standard APIs for connection because as Scoot pointed out, SIMD is a common "similar" scenario. I had thought I saw other research results from CUDA and OpenGL. We were going to use it as such in manufacturing image processing. We had our own execution engine, so that was a core requirement for us.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible on the managed stack. You do not have that tight of control over process execution.
If you need more strict control you will need to use native code, C, C++, Assembly. In addition, you will need strict control over process execution which means you need to be using a RTOS (Real Time Operating System). In no way can Windows (a non real time in-deterministic execution engine) accomplish this in any scenario.

You can pseudo control it by building your own execution engine and then managing the threads but this will only get you pseudo control. In the end, it will still be milliseconds apart in many cases.

RTOS is only truly RTOS because the architects run analysis on all tasks that are to be run and can determine if they can execute by their deadline. 
This has nothing to do with starting them at the same time. For that you will actually have to build firmware for the chip build APIs that you can signal a process start and all of your processors will start the loaded process. In other words, if you want to do this you have to get down to the metal and build APIs that allow each processor to start synchronously with the other.

It may be possible using something like CUDA (GPU computing) which is C++ and requires nVidia. OpenGL is the open stack and can likely do it on any GPU, but the fact is C# is a managed stack so you will have to go down to native code and also have access to hardware API that allows process syncing.

Comment: Wow.  Good answer.

Comment: The embedded versions of windows does have RTOS variants, but it is a very different programming environment and I would call it windows in name only.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain -- haha "wino"

Comment: this might be one of the most interesting answers/discussions I've seen on SO in months.